# Azure ML Workbench not deploying service even though its running?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

When running the command:

```
az ml service create realtime -f score.py --model-file model.hdf5 -s schema.json -n modelapp -r python --collect-model-data false -c aml_config\conda_dependencies.yml
```

The image and service both seem to be created. But after a while, this error comes up:

```
{
"Azure-cli-ml Version": "0.1.0a27.post3",
"Error": {
    "Error Message": "No response from health endpoint after multiple deploy attempts. Setting status to failed."
},
"Response Code": 500,
"Response Content": {
    "CreatedTime": "2018-02-16T14:40:56.358161Z",
    "EndTime": "2018-02-16T14:51:23.79374Z",
    "Error": {
        "Code": "DeploymentFailed",
        "Message": "No response from health endpoint after multiple deploy attempts. Setting status to failed.",
        "StatusCode": 500
    },
    "OperationType": "Service",
    "State": "Failed"
}
}
```

When I run the `az ml service logs realtime` command, I see many messages saying

```
2018-02-16T14:59:44.964990Z, INFO, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, , 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2018:14:59:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 7 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
```

I am using Azure ML Workbench version 0.1.1712.18263. This process has worked fine about a month ago when I first deployed an endpoint to this model management account. In Azure, I see the service with a status:Failed and no URL, but the primary and secondary keys are populated.

I tried reinstalling the software just in case it was an older version, but it did not help. What else can I do to make the endpoint active?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the AzureML team. We think that your issue is probably related to an error in your service code. Using the logs to troubleshoot is definitely the right approach, but from the snip you gave we aren't sure what the exact issue is. If you'd like to email the complete logs to amlfb@microsoft.com we will help you troubleshoot the issue.

Thanks, Serina

Comment: do you know if it's possible to put multiple code (score.py; like iris_score.py) files into the manifest?  we want to share code between training and deployment, and it doesn't make sense to cram everything into one file.